# reticulateパッケージのiterate関数の使い方を教えてください。

Tags: python, r

> library(reticulate)
>   x <- r_to_py(1:10)
>   x
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>   class(x)
>   [1] "python.builtin.list"   "python.builtin.object"
>   iterate(x)
>   Error in iterate(x) : iterate function called with non-iterator argument

なぜエラーなのかわかりません。
pythonのリストはiterableのはずです。
documentのほか、いろいろ探しましたがネットにはexampleも見つかりませんでした。
助けてください。